How do I ensure items in a horizontal RecyclerView has equal width, filling the entire screen without horizontal scrolling and avoiding empty spaces?
I have a horizontal RecyclerView displaying 5 items where each item is a LinearLayout containing TextViews for value and label. Despite setting layout_width="0dp" and layout_weight="1" for each item, they do not uniformly occupy the available width, resulting in some items expanding to fit their content (wrap_content) while others remain smaller. Also there is some empty space at the end.
Custom.xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linear_main"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:padding="8dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="3dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="3dp"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal">
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textview_value"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
            android:text="125"
            android:textSize="14sp"/>
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textview_label"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Advanced"
            android:textSize="10sp"/>
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>

Recyclerview
<androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
 android:id="@+id/recyclerview1"
 android:layout_width="match_parent"
 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
 android:orientation="horizontal"/>

On Create Viewholder
RecyclerView.LayoutParams layoutParams = new RecyclerView.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
view.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);

It has 5 items and I want the width be equally divided among 5 of them.
I tried adding weight, width property but nothing worked.

use GridLayoutManager
